# How to inserti if only some non key attributes of table do not match in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert data in mysql Db only if 2 non key attribute are not matching for example if I am fetching tweets from twitter and i want to check if the user name and tweet matches in Db then do not insert in Db else Insert and I dont want to keep user name and tweet as key attribute now I am using IF exist but not working

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE usernaem = 'someuser' and tweet='some tweet')
   BEGIN
       insert data in Db if not exists
   END
```

but getting error in IF EXISTS, I am using mysql.

Comment: You can only use `IF` statements in a stored procedure, not a query.

Comment: so what is solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you want to make a unique key for username and tweet?

Comment: I already have autoincrement id as unique

Comment: and a user name can have many tweets so cannot be unique

Comment: The unique key would be the combination `(username, tweet)`. This allows a user to have many tweets, just not duplicates of the same tweet. And you can have multiple unique indexes in a table.